# NSTextField and Auto Layout in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, interface-builder, nstableview

I've got a view-based NSTableView. I'm trying to understand the problem of why I cannot position / resize the NSTextField that resides in the NSTableCellView. I believe this problem is related to the intrinsic content size. Therefore I modified the Content Hugging and Compression Resistance to prioritise hugging. Please see screenshots of IB and the results when running the app.

Purple rectangle is the Custom View.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see the connection between the title of this question and the content of the question.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry, has been corrected now.